# php xpath : How to Select all Parent by skipping a specific child

Tags: php, xpath

I want to write an xpath expression that get the parent tags by skipping a specific child. Here is my source xml:

```
<root>
    <paren>
        <child1>10</child1>
        <child2>20</child2>
        <child3>30</child3>
    </paren>

    <paren>
        <child1>101</child1>
        <child2>202</child2>
        <child3>303</child3>
    </paren>
</root>
```

I want to skip `<child3>` and get the following output after the xpath:

```
<root>
    <paren>
        <child1>10</child1>
        <child2>20</child2>
    </paren>

    <paren>
        <child1>101</child1>
        <child2>202</child2>
    </paren>
</root>
```

I try with the following php code:

```
$output_xml = $input_xml->xpath('//paren/*[not(self::child3)]');
```

It gives following output [**Notice: pren & root tag missing**]:

```
<child1>10</child1>
<child2>20</child2>
<child1>101</child1>
<child2>202</child2>
```

How can I edit the xpath to retrieve expected output?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get that output using pure XPath. Element is a unit in XPath data model. Selecting `paren` element for example, means selecting the opening tag `<paren>`, closing tag `</paren>`, and everything in between. There is no such `paren` element that doesn't contain `child3` in the original XML which XPath query can return as you wanted.

What you're trying to do is more of an XML transformation, which normally done using XSLT or using your programming language of choice, presumably PHP.